# tiki-wiki: How to copy a structure into another Or how to duplicate a structure

Tags: tiki-wiki

I am new to tiki, I just learned about structures and I find them to be very useful and powerful. My requirement is to create a hierarchy of empty pages (essentially a hierarchy) and make users of the wiki to reuse that hierarchy while creating certain content. 
I find tiki structures to fit my needs of hierarchy perfectly. However, I can't find any way to duplicate a structure (so that users can have their own copy of it) and edit their own copy.

Is it possible in tiki and if so how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have two wiki pages of the same name so you need to use prefixes or suffixes.
You can make a dump of existing structure or XML zip and then copy paste the dump tree into new structure tree textarea or import the zip.
Then add the prefix or suffix manually. It will be something like:

```
My Structure
 Subpage 1
 Subpage 2
```

Modify it to:

```
user2 - My Structure
 user2 - Subpage 1
 user2 - Subpage 2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply luciash. So essentially, we will be creating new set of wiki pages with same "structure". I thought the same thing, however, I want to be able to do this automatically, not manually, is there any known plugin/extension/sample code which I can use for this? All my searches so far have been fruitless. Thanks again.

Comment: I fear there is no existing code example or working solution for this. It would need to be coded and implemented as a new sub-feature of Structures or Organic Groups (in development for Tiki 14 an 15): http://doc.tiki.org/Organic+Groups#contentog_tiki_versions-1